# How can I retrieve the exact point of contact between a bullet and an enemy, but not have the enemy "pushed" by the bullet?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on my first game in Unity. It's a 2d side-scroller/shooter.

For the bullet contacting an enemy, I was using `OnTriggerEnter2d` and this was working well until I wanted to place a sprite at the point of contact.

```cs
//Bullet.cs
void OnTriggerEnter2D(PolygonCollider2D hitInfo)
{
    var enemy = hitInfo.GetComponent<Enemy>();
    if (enemy != null && enemy.isAlive)
    {
        if (enemy.impactSprite != null)
            Instantiate(enemy.impactSprite, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);

        enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return;
    }
}
```

Because the bullet sprite is roughly 50 pixels wid, using its position to place the impact sprite didn't work properly - it was placed roughly 25px beside the enemy.

I googled and fiddled with how to get the exact contact point, and it seemed the common response was to use `OnCollisionEnter2D` instead of a trigger:

```cs
//Bullet.cs
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    var enemy = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>();
    if (enemy != null && enemy.isAlive)
    {
        if (enemy.impactSprite != null)
            Instantiate(enemy.impactSprite, collision.contacts[0].point, gameObject.transform.rotation);

        enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return;
    }
}
```

This places the impact sprite in the correct position, but because the bullet is no longer tagged as a trigger, it has physical interactions with the enemy. The collision pushes the enemy away. Messing with mass is a possible workaround but doesn't seems like just that - a workaround.

How can I get the exact collision point of these two objects without enabling physical interaction between the two?

(The bullet is using a PolygonCollider2D, and the enemy for now is just a box collider.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
//Bullet.cs
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D hitInfo)
{
    var enemy = hitInfo.GetComponent<Enemy>();
    if (enemy != null && enemy.isAlive)
    {
        if (enemy.impactSprite != null)
        {
            var hitPos = hitInfo.ClosestPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
            Instantiate(enemy.impactSprite, hitPos, gameObject.transform.rotation);
        }

        enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return;
    }
}
```

See [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.ClosestPoint.html) for more info.
Though in short, it gives you the position on the collider closest to the provided position. In your case the position on the enemy perimiter closest to the bullet position.

Comment: Thanks! As far as I know, the param for [`OnTriggerEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) has to be a `Collider2D`, no? I'll try changing it to `Collider2D` and foregoing the `GetComponent<>`.

Comment: Update: Taking your answer and making the small change noted in my previous comment did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Woops, didn't realize that the collider was the hitInfo, it's been a while since I've used Unity and it was late when I answered :'). But I edited my answer now. You could also leave the param to be PolygonCollider2D most likely and if that doesn't have the ClosestPoint method (probably will tho, since it inherits from Collider2D), you could still cast it to Collider2D, in your case just having the param being Collider2D is fine tho, since you don't make use of any of the polygon specific methods.